# Crystal lang : How to write binary Int to IO

Tags: crystal-lang

best practise?

**In binary format, please**

And the situation of BigEndian or LittleEndian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then it's [IO#write_bytes](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/IO.html#write_bytes%28object%2Cformat%3AIO%3A%3AByteFormat%3DIO%3A%3AByteFormat%3A%3ASystemEndian%29-instance-method). Endianess can be configured via argument `format`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It has a name doesn't like what in my image. [:smile_cry]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`IO#<<`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/IO.html#%3C%3C%28obj%29%3Aself-instance-method).

Comment: BTW the situation of BigEndian & LittleEndian ? thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean binary format. I have changed my question. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string, ex: `3.to_s`

Comment: Excuse me but I want the binary format. I have changed my question, sorry.